# Export and use a IIFE class in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, model, iife

I'm trying to do a model class with privacy, so I have this class with clousures in *Answer* model file:

```
export class Answer {
  getId;
  getText;

  constructor(id: string, text: string) {
    const idPrivate = id;
    const textPrivate = text;

    this.getId = () => idPrivate;
    this.getText = () => textPrivate;
  }
}
```

So I can use it in this way in other files:

```
import {Answer} from '../shared/model/Answer';
...
const answers: Array<Answer> = [];
answers.push(new Answer('1', '1'));
```

Now, with ES6 we have *Symbol*, so I'm trying to do the same, but I have problems to export and use the function. This is the code:

```
const Answer = (() => {
  const idPrivate = Symbol();
  const textPrivate = Symbol();

  class Answer {
    constructor(id: string, text: string) {
      this[idPrivate] = id;
      this[textPrivate] = text;
    }

    getId() {
      return this[idPrivate];
    }

    getText() {
      return this[textPrivate];
    }
  }

  return Answer;
})();

export {Answer};
```

How can I use this IIFE function? For example for this code:

```
const answer = Answer('ss', 'ss');
```

I get this error message: "Method expression is not of Function type". How can I call the *Answer* constructor?

Comment: you are exporting class `Answer` and calling it like a function? use `new` for class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe we call classes with 'new', like : new Answer()

Comment: Yes, the problems was that when I create "const answers: Array<Answer> = [];" I get an error with "Unresolved type Answer", how can I define an array of Answers?

Comment: Isn't doing const answers= [] ok?

Comment: Using TS is not better defined the array type?